# How to store week-days as a CSV in a string field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My intention is to display 7 checkboxes, 1 for each day of the week, and save it in a single field in a table, in CSV format. (So, Sunday,Wednesday would be saved as string `0,3`)

So, I am able to get the CSV of the selected week days into the field.

But when I edit the form, all the checkboxes are unchecked.
How do I get the checkboxes to be selected, based upon the CSV in the field?>

This is how I am showing the checkboxes in the form:

```
<% Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index do |day,index| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "post[week_days_#{index}]", index, false, 
                    :name => "post[week_days][]" %>
<% end %>
```

Output is:

```
...
<input id="post_week_days_0" name="post[week_days][]" type="checkbox" value="0" />
<input id="post_week_days_1" name="post[week_days][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
...
```

I think I have to change the form like below (added the `:checked` option):

```
<%= check_box_tag "post[week_days_#{index}]", index, false,
                  :name => "post[_week_days][]", 
                  :checked => (post.week_days.include? index ? true : false) %>
```

But how will I get the `include?` to work, since the field is a string, and I somehow need that string as an array?

**Ps.** This is the way I am trying to implement this, but if there is some better way to do this, I could use that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
:checked => (post.week_days.include? index.to_s)
```

You dont have to give ?(ternary) condition because .include? returns true or false